# Angular-js: How to use of ng-click with ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I have created a chatbox in angular JS and now I want to show notification bubble when ever I click on any user. I tried to use this with ng-click and and ng-if but failed.
Here is the code I am using

```
     <div class="people"  >
            <div ng-repeat="user in allCompanyUsers">
                <div class="person" ng-click="activateChat(user)" id="chat_{{user.id}}">
                    <img alt="" />
                    <span class="name" >{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
                    <span   ng-show="!user.showNotification" class="noti_bubble">5</span> 


                    <span class="preview"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And on controller side:

```
    $scope.showNotification = false;

    $scope.allCompanyUsers = AllCompanyUsers.query();

    $scope.activateChat = function(user){
        console.log(user);

        $scope.activeConversations = [];
        UserMessages.query({toUser:user.login}).$promise.then(function(data) {
               angular.forEach(data, function(message) {
                   $scope.activeConversations.push({'message':message.message,'type':message.type, 'time': message.time});
               });
        });

        $scope.activePerson=user.login;
        $scope.showNotification = true;
        $scope.isDisabled=true;
            /*$scope.activeConversations=user.chat;*/
        $('.left .person').removeClass('active');
        var el = angular.element( document.querySelector('#chat_'+user.id));
        el.addClass('active');   
    };
```

Currently the count is hardcoded.
Here All users are showing with 5 bubble but I want that only selected user will show the bubble...

any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: is there any state for identify a user in all users?

Comment: Could you provide the implementation of the activateChat( ) function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wabt to use it with ng-if :

```
<div ng-if="bubble">
    //bubble code : set bubble to false when it close
    // use currentUser variable
</div>

<button ng-click="currentUser = user;bubble=true"></button>
```

Note that i changed div by button for ng-click, because i'm not sure whetver div element support click event, so go for button or a or select tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think one option is to set a property for your view model called **selected**. In your Angular controller, when you click on a user, you should set the value of this property to true.

```
$scope.user.selected = true;
```

And only show the bubble count associated to that specific user if it has been selected

```
<span ng-show="user.selected" class="noti_bubble">{{user.bubbleCount}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="people"  >
            <div ng-repeat="user in allCompanyUsers">
                <div class="person" ng-click="activateChat(user)" id="chat_{{user.id}}">
                    <img alt="" />
                    <span class="name" >{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
                    <span ng-class="user != 0 ? 'noti_bubble' : ''"</span> 
                    <span class="preview"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```